# OR-TOOLS Job Shop Scheduling - stop when find first feasible solution

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am trying to implement Job Shop Scheduling with CP-SAT, but I have more than 20000 tasks to schedule and finding optimal solution will take too much time. I'm using solver time limit, but sometimes it gives me feasible solution in assumed time and sometimes not. Could anyone show how to limit solver to find the first feasible solution?

https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop

I know that I should use SolveWithSolutionCallback, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the parameter: `stop_after_first_solution` to true.

See the [definition](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5425dedcfbb22cb74c636c1374a9b5ad684b1eb5/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto#L1117).